# I cant get data from day where I drop in full calendar

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, fullcalendar

I have this fullcalendar:

```
          $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                height: 700,
                locale: 'es',
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next, month basicWeek today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: ''
                },
                buttonText: {
                    today: 'Hoy',
                    month: 'Mes',
                    week: 'Semana'
                },
                editable: true,
                weekends: true,
                droppable: true, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar
                dragRevertDuration: 0,
                events: $scope.events,
                drop: function(date, jsEvent, ui, resourceId) {
                    console.log("DROP!")
                }
            });
```

I would like in drop event, get data of this day.

[image]

I drag event and drop in day 1, that it has an event called "Carmen Donoso | BAJA", and when I drop it I would like to get this event.

Thanks

Comment: the drop event relates to the event you're dropping, not the rest of the day. It does give you the date on which the event was dropped though, so if you want you can call this: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/clientEvents/ using a filter function (as described in that link) which checks the date of each event to see if it matches the date from the drop event. Then you can return only the events matching the same day.

Comment: And how can I get the day where I drop? @ADyson

Comment: `drop: function(date, jsEvent, ui, resourceId) {` the first parameter "date" gives you the date where the event is dropped. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/dropping/drop/ for more detail

Comment: Yes!! thank you very much!! :)

Comment: Hi,@ADyson now, I would like to get event when I hover mouse with event over the cell of day.. thanks..

Comment: Try reading these: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/mouse/